# Save a formset of custom forms django

Tags: python, django, django-models, formsets

I am trying to save a formset in django.
To do so I have my model and a customized form.
Then I create my formset this way :

```
QuoteFormSet = formset_factory(QuoteForm, extra=2)
formset = QuoteFormset(request.POST)
```

But when I do formset.save() i get `AttributeError: 'QuoteFormFormSet' object has no attribute 'save'`

my model :

```
class Quote(models.Model):
    country = models.CharField(max_length=2,)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=100,)
```

My form:

```
class QuoteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Quote
    country = forms.ChoiceField(choices=COUNTRIES, required=False)
    street = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok I had to use `modelformset` instead of `formset`

```
from django.forms.models import modelformset_factory

def new_quote(request):
    QuoteFormSet = modelformset_factory(Quote, form=QuoteForm, extra=2)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = QuoteFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            #
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        formset = QuoteFormSet()

    return render(request, 'request_quote_form.html', {
    'formset': formset,
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't instantiate the formset.

```
formset = QuoteFormset(request.POST)
```

Comment: i did it but forgot to add it to my post >_<

Answer (score 1):

Formset has no attribute as save. So, try saving form objects in formset one by one. It will work.

```
if formset.is_valid():
    formset = QuoteFormset(request.POST) 
    for form in formset:
       form.save()
```

Comment: However, this will save also forms of the formset that have been marked for deletion.